# Is there a way to view git history using external diff tool?

Tags: git, diff

When I view a git commit history in git gui, is there a way to use an external diff tool to show commit differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, `git difftool`. For example:

```
git difftool -t gvimdiff master^..master
```

If you're talking about `git-gui` - it uses `gitk` internally for viewing history. You can configure an external diff tool using Edit->Preferences. It's a little tricky to see where it's used: When viewing a difference normally (either by selecting a commit or using the various "Diff this -> selected" options), using "Patch" view on the right-hand panel, right-click a file and select "External Diff". This will use the diff tool you configured.

Comment: And do not forget you can configure Git to use a particular diff tool by default through several `git config` commands. See **[here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool.html)** for information on the configuration variables to set.

Comment: I was asking about integrating git gui with external diff tool.

Comment: @seticer, I've extended the answer to explain for `git-gui`. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: i.e. it's impossible to replace this diff http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/images/11.png with external diff?

Comment: I It isn't possible, probably because of the stage/unstage actions, as shown in your screenshot. There are alternative git GUI tools though.

Comment: +1000 for "right-click a file and select external diff" - a very unintuitive design - thanks for pointing this out