# Gui for git to select revision to compare?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-gui, gitk, git-difftool

I want to compare different revisions of a single file.
On the commandline I can do this by

`git difftool <revision_1>:<file_1> <revision_2>:<file_2>`.

But I want to use a gui to select which revisions are compared.
So, the gui should show a list of commits where the specified file is changed and from this list two commits should be selectable which are then passed to the actual difftool.

`gitk -p file`

Does something similar but it only generates diffs between succeeding commits. (And the output is just conventional diff and not side-by-side difftool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20604472/333403) I found a solution my self, which does not need additional software:

gitk can be configured to use an external difftool (like kdiff3)

Edit->Preferences->...

Then one uses

`gitk -p <file>` -> Select revision1 and right-click on revision2  -> "diff selected -> this" -> in the right-hand panel right-click on the file and select "external diff-tool".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rabbitvcs](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu) for SVN and GIT, it is a GUI tool similar to TortoiseSVN in Windows